# Circular iterator / generator for list of custom class items

Tags: java, iterator, generator

Say I have a custom class:

```
public class CustomClass {
    private String name;
    private String data;

    public CustomClass(String name, String data) {
        this.name = name;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I also have a list of my custom class objects:

```
CustomClass[] list = new CustomClass[] {
    new CustomClass("Item 1", "data"),
    new CustomClass("Item 2", "data"),
    new CustomClass("Item 3", "data"),
    new CustomClass("Item 4", "data"),
    new CustomClass("Item 5", "data"),
};
```

How can I create an iterator (or, rather, generator) to iterate through the list K times (K > list.length) giving me next element every time?

**I prefer an "inline" solution (without creating any new classes).**

Say, I need to get my CustomClass list items one after another K = 7 times. The solution should retrieve me following CustomClass objects:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 1
- Item 2

Comment: `Iterator` is an interface. To create a new type of iterator, you *have* to create a new class, even if just an anonymous one.

Comment: @Andreas true - I guess I meant avoiding definitions somewhere outside my main function, as I want to maintain readability of the code.

Answer (score 6):

Use the index modulo array length:

```
for( int i = 0; i < K; i++ ) {
   list[ i % list.length ];
}
```

When it comes to first index (here it's named `i`) greater or equal to list length, it will "reset" it, because operation modulo (`%`) returns the remainder after integer division.

The solution does not introduce any classes.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
static <T> Iterator<T> circularIterator(List<T> list, int count) {
    int size = list.size();
    return new Iterator<T>() {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < count;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return list.get(i++ % size);
        }
    };
}
```

And

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
for (Iterator<String> i = circularIterator(list, 5); i.hasNext();) {
    String s = i.next();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

result:

```
a
b
c
a
b
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do this is:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables
import com.google.common.collect.Iterators;

Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
Iterator<Integer> iter = Iterators.limit(Iterables.cycle(arr).iterator(),7) ;
```

Comment: Add Iterators.limit() to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Java 8 friendly way:

```
IntStream.range(0, K)
    .mapToObj(i -> list[i % list.length])
    .forEach(cc -> /* play with CustomClass cc instance */);
```

Comment: `.map` -> `.mapToObj`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a cyclic iterator, you could use Apache `commons-collections4`'s [`LoopingIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/LoopingIterator.html) or [`LoopingListIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/LoopingListIterator.html):

> The iterator will loop continuously around the provided elements, unless there are no elements in the collection to begin with, or all the elements have been removed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.LoopingIterator;

void circularIterator() {
  CustomClass[] list = new CustomClass[]{
      new CustomClass("Item 1", "data"),
      new CustomClass("Item 2", "data"),
      new CustomClass("Item 3", "data"),
      new CustomClass("Item 4", "data"),
      new CustomClass("Item 5", "data"),
  };

  final Iterator<CustomClass> circularIterator =
      new LoopingIterator(Arrays.asList(list));
  while (circularIterator.hasNext()) {
    CustomClass next = circularIterator.next();
    System.out.println(next.getName());
  }
}
```

The code produces:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 1
...
// This would never end
```